# Sql server - Using aggregate functions in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a sql query for Transport business, this query when executed should get the drivers information who got more than 20% star rating(5*) rating from his customers in last 30 days... also that should be a minimum of 5 trips..

Lets say if a driver completed 100 trips in last 30 days and he received 30 star rating (5*) feedback then this Driver and all his star (5*) Trips information should be retrieved by the query..this driver has completed more than 20% 5 star trips

```
select tr.[TripId], tr.[DriverId], tr.[Rating], dr.[DriverName]
from tblTripInfo
left outer join tblDriver dr
on tr.[DriverId] = dr.[DriverId]
where tr.[Rating] = 5 and tr.[TripDate] >= GetDate() - 30
```

the above query gets all the information of trips and driver who got 5* ratings in last 30 days, i want to get only those who have minimum of 20% 5* trips out of their total trips and that should me minimum of 5 trips

Initially i wanted to get only DriverId's who met the above condition and the below query worked

```
select DriverId, 
count(case when Rating = 5 then DriverId end) as TotalStars,
100.0 * avg(case when Rating = 5 then 1.0 else 0 end) as Average5Stars
from tblTripInfo
where TripDate >= GetDate() - 30 
group by DriverId
having 
  count(case when Rating = 5 then DriverId end) > 10 
  and  
  100.0 * avg(case when Rating = 5 then 1.0 else 0 end) > 25
```

But now i want to get all the information like tripId, driverName, trip date of those 5* trips as well

Comment: If you want aggregate functions as a filter, you want `having`, not `where`. A basic guide to aggregation should help you with this.

Comment: yeah but if i directly use avg() function in the above query it will not get the correct results

Comment: Show what you tried, what results you got, and an explanation why those are wrong

Comment: updated my post

Answer (score 0):

You need something in the line of this:

```
WITH TotalTrips as (
SELECT Count() as TotalTrips,
DriverId
FROM tblTripInfo
GROUP BY DriverId
)

SELECT DriverId, 
count(case when Rating = 5 then DriverId end) as Total5StarTrips,
100.0 * avg(case when Rating = 5 then 1.0 else 0 end) as Average5Stars
FROM tblTripInfo t1

JOIN TotalTrips t2
ON t1.DriverId = t2.DriverId
AND t2.TotalTrips > 5 --more than 5 trips

where TripDate >= GetDate() - 30 
group by DriverId

HAVING COUNT(case when Rating = 5 then DriverId end) / t2.TotalTrips > 0.2 --more than 20% 5-starred trips
```

No need of complicated logic if you can use some SubQuery for simplicity.